# Как отсортировать список строк по возрастанию?

Tags: python, сортировка

Есть большой список строк, отличающихся только цифрами. Например, отсортировать список так, чтобы из этого `[:son1 ','son10','son11','son2','son20','son3','son4']` получилось это `['son1','son2','son3','son4','son10','son11','son20']`. У меня не получается понять, как работает параметр `key` в методе `sort()`, а обычная функция работает некорректно

Comment: Сейчас это у вас не строки, а названия переменных. А так вам поможет sort, lambda, срез и функция int.

Comment: Так, уже лучше. Вам надо написать в `key=` такую `lambda` функцию, которая будет вырезать из ваших строк числовую часть и делать её прямо вот числом и тогда сортировка правильно сработает. Что для этого нужно я выше написал, думайте.